# In Flash CS3 fonts work in workspace, but in exported SWF they do not show up

Tags: flash, flash-cs3

I have an fla, and I'm using a font that works and looks fine in the workspace. And it is just static text. However when I export the swf and play the swf, the fonts do not appear at all. And I'm playing the swf on a laptop that has the font installed.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set your text as (Static text & Use device fonts) because if its set to (anti-alias for animation or any other style) then text will not show in .swf , i have try this thing personally.. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

check that the text field is definitely a "static" TextField. Static text fields always embed the characters of the font that they need. You should only have font problems if it is a dynamic or input text field.

Comment: thats the problem. It is definitely static. In fact when I make it dynamic and embed it automatically it works fine, yet as soon as i change it back to static the font doesn't show up at all, and it just defaults to the default font.